# python /Django filtering data

Tags: python, django, logic

I am quite new to Programming ,I have created 3 model

1. children
   fields : name , is_active and is_sponsored
2. Sponsor
   fields : Name
3. Sponsorship
   fields :children(foreign key), sponsor(foreign key), start_date and end_date.

i need to set a condition only those only those children shall be displayed that have less than 2 sponsorship on current date and are active.

i have already set filter in sponsorshipForm relating to is_sponsored. but to check and change is_sponsored value with regards to above condition.

basically i and unable to write logic for the above condition

please help

Comment: perhaps you don't need is_sponsored field in your Children class.
If you want to check if a children has sponsor or not, you can add a method in Children class, in this method ,you can query how many sponsor related to this children.

Comment: even if put method how i will able to filter in sponsorship form, Elaborate

Comment: Can you post your SponsorshipForm? Do you mean you want to limit the choices for the children field?

Answer (score 0):

i think your queryset will be like this

```
from django.utils import timezone
from django.db.models.aggregates import Count
# Don't forget to import your Sponsorship model


sponsorships = Sponsorship.objects.filter(
    children__is_sponsored=True # Child is sponsored 
).filter(
    start_date__lte=timezone.now(), end_date__gte=timezone.now() # To make sure that sponsorship is active
).annotate(
    count_children=Count('children')
).filter(
    count_children__lt=2 # Less than 2
)
```